# Storing questions and user answers in localstorage to reduce database and server load

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, server

I am making a quiz application. I am wondering if storing questions and user's answer to localstorage then submit once completed is good and effective way to reduce database / server load if let say I have 2,000 concurrent users? Or are there any alternative way?

PS.
I'm using a shared hosting.

Comment: Let's say you don't, because you don't. This is premature optimization. Don't worry about performance until you have a *meaasurable* performance problem. I really doubt your server will buckle if you have hundreds of people answering questions once per minute.

Comment: If you're anticipating a certain load, **build a load simulator** to validate any approach, and be sure you've got extensive instrumentation to capture performance data reliably, and importantly, in a form that can be easily compared.

Comment: I'm using a shared hosting. We have experienced website accessibility problems (error 503, slow loading) when there a hundred or less concurrent users.

Comment: Shared hosting is awfully unpredictable in terms of performance. Maybe it's your fault, or maybe you're just on a low performing tier. Without knowing the limits of your platform, it's hard to say if you're doing anything wrong, or your provisioned service is just not up to scratch. It's worth noting that there's a lot of options here, so try out other services if you want to get more data.

Comment: Remember, there's options like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) geared towards your use case that might be better than bashing something together on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna store a few questions sure.
But generally I would recommend using the IndexedDB instead.
[IndexedDB on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)

The honorable gentlemen suggested load testing, but for such a small application that seems overkill, probably takes more time to setup if you never used one than it's worth.

I would also suggest using a cache (eg. Redis) on the server side.

Comment: there are around 600 questions. If I can't store that much I am thinking of chunking it to a hundred or at very least by 10s. I think you get my point in reducing database and server load. So indexDB is a good way to address this issue? I'll look more into it. Thank you

Comment: @Rick go for IndexedDB.